# Adding link to a cell - invalid procedure

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bigger code that makes my daily work much easier, everything works just fine, only one part that links cell A to a specific worksheet bugs. When I change the value of the cell from numbers into text, the code works. I don't know enough about vba to figure out the problem.

The part that should do the trick but fails, is the one after : Add hyperlink to the cell in Column A of the corresponding row

Can anyone help?

```
    Dim selectedRow As Range
    Set selectedRow = Selection.EntireRow

    Dim sheetName As String
    sheetName = selectedRow.Cells(1, "A").Value

    sheetName = Trim(sheetName)

    If sheetName <> "" Then
        Dim templatePath As String
        templatePath = "H:\Documents\Custom Office Templates\"
        Dim templateFile As String
        templateFile = "NewSheet.xltm"
        If Dir(templatePath & templateFile) <> "" Then
            Dim templateWorkbook As Workbook
            Set templateWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(templatePath & templateFile)
            
            Dim templateSheet As Worksheet
            Set templateSheet = templateWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            templateSheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
            Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
            Set NewSheet = ActiveSheet

            Dim overviewSheet As Worksheet
            Set overviewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview")
            
            NewSheet.Range("B3").Value = overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "A").Value
            NewSheet.Range("B4").Value = overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "I").Value
            NewSheet.Range("B10").Value = overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "D").Value
            NewSheet.Range("B11").Value = overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "E").Value
            NewSheet.Range("B12").Value = overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "F").Value
            NewSheet.Range("B13").Value = overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "G").Value
            NewSheet.Name = sheetName
            
         
            
            ' Add hyperlink to the cell in Column A of the corresponding row
            overviewSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "A"), _
            Address:="Rapports.xlsm", _
            SubAddress:="'" & sheetName & "'!A1", _
            TextToDisplay:=overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "A").Value
            
                    
                   
            ' Folder unhand vun der JDA
            Dim folderPath As String
            folderPath = "Some folder\another folder\" & sheetName & "_*"
            
            ' Find the matching folder
            Dim matchingFolder As String
            matchingFolder = Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory)

            If matchingFolder <> "" Then
                Dim folderAddress As String
                folderAddress = "more folders\folder\" & matchingFolder
                
                    
                ' Link op de Folder am J:// am Overview op Zeil D
                overviewSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "E"), _
                   Address:=folderAddress, _
                   TextToDisplay:=overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "E").Value
                ' Link op de Folder am J:// um neien Sheet
                NewSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=NewSheet.Range("M3"), _
                    Address:=folderAddress, _
                    TextToDisplay:=NewSheet.Range("M3").Value
     
                     
            Else
                MsgBox "Kee Folder mat der JDA " & sheetName & " fonnt."
            End If
          
           templateWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Else
            MsgBox "Template file 'NewSheet.xltm' leit net an dem richtege Folder"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Wiel eng rei aus an dro deng JDA an der Spalte A an"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What cell are you talking about when say "When I change the value of the cell from numbers into text, the code works"? If the one where from you take `TextToDisplay`, try using `CStr(overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "E").Value)`, even if the method definition says something about a `Variant` type...

Comment: The content of Cell A contains a number for example 123456. The code grabs this number and creates a new worksheet and calls it 123456. After that it should link the according cell A to the worksheet. But it doesnt work. When i put text into that cell, for example "Hello", the code calls the new worksheet hello and links the cell to it how it should work.
The part where i add a link to cell E, works just fine.

Comment: Did you read my comment up to the end? If so, did you try what I suggested there and still have the same problem?

Comment: Yes sorry i didn't tell you. I tryed and it didn't work.

Comment: There are three code lines adding hyperlinks. Do all of them suffer of the problem you describe? If not, which of them raises the error?

Comment: This one raises the error: `overviewSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "A"), _
            Address:="Rapports.xlsm", _
            SubAddress:="'" & sheetName & "'!A1", _
            TextToDisplay:=overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "A").Value `

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem.

The problem was in this part:
`overviewSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "A"), _ Address:="Rapports.xlsm", _ SubAddress:="'" & sheetName & "'!A1", _ TextToDisplay:=overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "A").Value`

The TextToDisplay part checks the value of cell A in the selected row.
But at this time, the code is already on the new created worksheet - Code parts from before --
So the solution is to use the already existing variable `NewSheet`

The working part of the code reads now like this:

`overviewSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=overviewSheet.Cells(selectedRow.Row, "A"), _ Address:="Rapports.xlsm", _ SubAddress:="'" & sheetName & "'!A1", _ TextToDisplay:=sheetName`

Pretty easy.. but I've had this problem for a few weeks now ;)